# Special matrices with determinant 0

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, determinant

Define a quadratic matrix A with n rows and n columns by filling it with consecutive
primes, starting with some prime p. The object is, to find the least starting prime p,
such that A has determinant 0 , if there is one.

For n=3 , PARI yields

[2213 2221 2237]

[2239 2243 2251]

[2267 2269 2273]

Is there a solution for each n>2 ?

Solutions I found so far :

3  2213

4  73

5  659

6  753937

I am currently searching for the case n=7.

Comment: For n=2, there is no solution because ad - bc = 0 is impossible for distinct primes a,b,c,d.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this could be answered using known theorems.

Comment: is there a singular $n\times n$-matrix with prime entries $2,3,5,7,\ldots,$ ?

Comment: Just for the reference, the smallest $7\times 7$ matrix should start with $775011673$ (and, nicely enough, it can start with any of the three subsequent primes too).

Comment: Well done, Peter!

Comment: Quick, and not too useful observation: Existence of such matrix for any $n\geq 3$ is a simple corollary of the (unproven) conjecture stating that there are arbitrarily long [CPAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutive_primes_in_arithmetic_progression): any CPAP-($3n$) produces a matrix with three linearly dependent rows and thus zero determinant.

Comment: And since I'm spamming this question already, the smallest $8\times 8$ matrix apparently starts with $54889300747$.