# Give an example of a singular matrix in $M_{3×3}(Q)$ the entries of which are distinct prime positive integers, or show that no such matrix can exist.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that the matrix exist because the entries are primes but I don´t know how to explain, i need some help.
Give an example of a singular matrix in $M_{3×3}(Q)$ the entries of which are distinct prime positive integers, or show that no such matrix can exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\pmatrix{5&7&11\cr17&19&23\cr41&43&47\cr}$$ EDIT: Also, but not obvious,  $$\pmatrix{2&3&5\cr7&11&13\cr17&19&101\cr}$$

Answer (score 4):

With the first $9$ primes you get the following examples which are not equivalent under row or column permutations:
$$\left[\matrix{2&19&13\cr 11&3&5\cr 7&23&17\cr}\right],\quad
\left[\matrix{2&19&5\cr 11&3&17\cr 7&23&13\cr}\right],\quad
\left[\matrix{2&5&3\cr 13&7&11\cr 17&23&19\cr}\right]\ .$$
Here is another one, obtained from choosing randomly $9$ from the first $60$ primes:
$$\left[\matrix{13&191&163\cr 31&137&151\cr 17&271&229\cr}\right]\ .$$

Comment: Very nice! +1. Did you foresee that examples can be constructed using the first nine primes, or did you just want to try your luck?

Comment: @user1551: I wrote a program that accepts a list of $9$ primes as input and computes all 5040 essentially different determinants.

Answer (score 3):

There should be simpler examples using smaller primes, but you may fill the matrix with nine primes from [CPAP-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression#Largest_known_consecutive_primes_in_AP) to get a rank-2 matrix. See also the related question: [Special matrices with determinant 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612870/special-matrices-with-determinant-0).