# If the entries of a matrix are sines of distinct prime numbers, could the determinant equal $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, prime-numbers, determinant

I recently [learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4765979/398708) that if the entries of a matrix are sines of distinct integers, the determinant could equal $0$. For example,

$\det\begin{bmatrix}\sin 1 & \sin 2 & \sin 3 \\ \sin 4 & \sin 5 & \sin 6 \\ \sin 7 & \sin 8 & \sin 9\end{bmatrix}=0$

And I [learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631135/398708) that if the entries of a matrix are distinct prime numbers, the determinant could equal $0$. For example,

$\det\begin{bmatrix}3&5&7\\13&17&19\\23&29&31\end{bmatrix}=0$

This leads to my question:

> If the entries of a matrix are *sines of distinct prime numbers*, could the determinant equal $0$ ?

I have tried to apply the ideas contained in the answers and comments in the links above, to prove that the answer to my question is yes, without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n \geq 3$, then for any constants $m, b_1, \ldots, b_n$, the any $n \times n$ matrix with respective $(i, j)$ entries
$$\sin[b_i + (j - 1) m]$$ has determinant $0$; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765986/155629) for a slick proof.

So, to answer our question in the affirmative it suffices to find $n$ nonoverlapping sequences of $n$ primes in arithmetic progression with the same common difference $m$. (It turns out that $m$ must be divisible by the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $n\#$ of $n$.)

For $n = 3$ we can take $m = 6$ (since $3\# = 6$, $m = 6$ the smallest possible value), that is, choose any $3$ nonoverlapping [sexy prime triplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime#Sexy_prime_triplets) $(b_i, b_i + 6, b_i + 12)$ of primes. The lexicographically first example is $b_1 = 5, b_2 = 7, b_3 = 31$:
$$\det \pmatrix{\sin 5 & \sin 11 & \sin 17 \\ \sin 7 & \sin 13 & \sin 19 \\ \sin 31 & \sin 37 & \sin 43} = 0 .$$

For $n = 4$ we can again take $m = 6$ and so use [sexy prime quadruplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime#Sexy_prime_quadruplets) $(b_i, b_i + 6, b_i + 12, b_i + 18)$, but for $n \geq 5$, $m$ must be divisible by $5\# = 30$.

The [Green-Tao Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) implies that one can find matrices of sines of primes of arbitrarily large size satisfying this property, and moreover that we can demand that all $n^2$ primes that appear form an arithmetic sequence.